# can REST post/put have request parameter and no request payload

Tags: rest, post, put, payload

I am working on REST APIs. 
can REST API post/put can include request parameters without a request payload?
where I can find the standard REST specifications

Answer (score 0):

There are no "standard REST specifications". REST is defined by Roy Fielding's thesis [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm). The HTTP verbs POST and PUT are defined in [rfc 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). REST doesn't necessarily mean a HTTP transport - it is an architectural style which is well suited to web based APIs. Part of that style is that the definition of a service is determined entirely by the contents of messages passed, specifically the way they contain references to other parts of the service (i.e. hyperlinks). As such, if it makes sense for your API to create an empty resource an empty PUT request would be a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: but apache cxf dose not an empty request payload for PUT/POST methods.i have not test jersey. it seems implementations make request payload a must for PUT/POST